# Can married women do abishekam on shivalingam at home?

Tags: shiva, practice, shiva-lingam, women

We have a very small thumb size, black colour shivalingam at home. Can my mother and me do abishekam on it?

Also I want to know the difference between laghurudram and Mahārudram .Which helps in fulfilling one's desires? If any one could shed light on these subjects, it would be great.

Comment: You should ask your question in lower case letters and register on this site. Questions asked by unregistered users may not get answers.

Comment: You should also not seek personal advice on this site. So you should remove all personal details from the question. simply ask if married woman can perform Rudra Abhisekham or not ..

Comment: Please register. Rudram chanting satisfies our desires. But that shouldn't be limited to material desires. In fact, there are other ways to get our desires fulfilled(by chanting stotras, performing vratas etc.,). Rudram is a vedic mantra. This should not  be done by women(if you meant that.If there is a qualified person in your family who can chant rudram, he can do it. If no, then do it by a qualified priest).

Comment: @SreeCharan Rudram chanting doesn't mere satisfy desires.

Comment: Yes you can very well do it. But try to learn proper annotations from a genuine source,